# WordPress Database Array Not Passing Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to create a form that allows someone to save a row of information into the wpdb. For some reason when I submit the form nothing is stored in the table. I took everything off the form and I'm able to submit the "name" value and it stores in the database but once I add more fields to the form and try to add the data to the array nothing happens. Here's what I have so far.

```
function elh_insert_into_db() {

global $wpdb;
// creates safety_users in database if not exists
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "safety_users"; 
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
    `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` text NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (`id`)
) $charset_collate;";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
// starts output buffering
ob_start();
?>
<form action="#v_form" method="post" id="v_form">
    <label for="first_name"><h3>First Name</h3></label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
    <label for="last_name"><h3>Last Name</h3></label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
// does the inserting, in case the form is filled and submitted
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["first_name"] != "" ) {
    $table = $wpdb->prefix."safety_users";
    $name = ($_POST["first_name"]);
    $lname = ($_POST["last_name"]);
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table, 
        array( 
            'name' => $name,
            'lname' => $lname
        )
    );
    $html = "<p>Your name <strong>$name</strong> was successfully recorded. Thanks!!</p>";
}
// if the form is submitted but the name is empty
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["first_name"] == "" )
    $html .= "<p>You need to fill the required fields.</p>";
// outputs everything
return $html;

}
// adds a shortcode you can use: [insert-into-db]
add_shortcode('elh-db-insert', 'elh_insert_into_db');
```

If anyone see's any mistakes in my code please let me know!

Comment: You mentioned the first name was saving, but not the last name, is it related to this? `    $name = s($_POST["first_name"]); $lname = ($_POST["last_name"]);` missing the "s"? change `($_POST["last_name"])` to `s($_POST["last_name"])`?

Comment: I just fixed that I just have typed that when I was copying over the code because it's not like that on my site but thanks for noticing!

Comment: np, I'm no mySql pro, but don't you need to add columns for each param? Your Create Table statement is only adding the id & name columns, I'd expect there to be a lname ```$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
    `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` text NOT NULL,    `lname` text NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (`id`)
) $charset_collate;";```

Comment: This is extremely poorly written and unsafe code.  Read up on sanitising data before inserting it into a database.  If you go live with this current code someone will hack your site.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andrew, I'm actually still learning so I'm going to look into the codex and improve my site. Its actually just a project I'm building for my portfolio so I have all the time in the world to improve it and the help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="v_form">
```

Instead of:

```
<form action="#v_form" method="post" id="v_form">
```

Replace `index.php` with the name of your PHP file.

Edit:
There seems to be an error at.

```
$name = s($_POST["first_name"]);
```

Remove the "s" before `($_POST`

Comment: I tried this with no luck unfortunately. This is a shortcode that exists in the functions.php file so I tried to use form action index.php and also with it just black "" and neither recorded to the database

Comment: What is the name of the file where this table is? If it is `functions.php` then you need `action="functions.php"`

Comment: Another idea would be to use mysql_query() two times for both first name and last name instead of using array()

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at myPHPadmin I was able to create columns for last name and then whatever else I would submit and it's all adding to the database now that the columns don't need to be created.